# How to pass data to another viewcontroller's function using segues?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass data from one ViewController to function in another ViewController. Function init must take input from first view controller and assign it to `goalDescription` and `goalTypes` variables.

I do the following:

First ViewController

```swift
 @IBAction func nextBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) { 
     if goalTextView.text != "" {
            guard let finishGoalVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FinishGoalVC") as? FinishGoalVC else { return }
            finishGoalVC.initData(description: goalTextView.text!, type: goalType)            
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "finishGoalVC", sender: self)
```

Second ViewController

```swift
 var goalDescription: String!
 var goalType: GoalType!  

    func initData(description: String, type: GoalType) {
        self.goalDescription = description
        self.goalType = type
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and what would you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data between ViewControllers appropriately, you need to override `prepare(for:sender:)` function.

In your case:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "finishGoalVC" { //in case you have multiple segues
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? FinishGoalVC {
            viewController.goalDescription = goalTextView.text! // be careful about force unwrapping.
            viewController.goalType = type  
        }
    }
}
```